# What causes "file being used by another application"?

Tags: filehandle

I have Win 7 Home Premium.

When I see the Windows Explorer message `file is being used by another application`, I use File Manager to see what apps are open. If closing all the apps does not help, I use `Unlocker`. I'm not a techie.

Question:  Is it fair to say that the error message is due to  the programmer not using a statement such as `fclose`, or could there be other reasons? If so, what other reasons are possible?

BTW:  no errors are reported by any apps prior to seeing the `file is being used...` message.

Added for clarification:  When the repeatedly offending app is closed, the file error message is still presented if I try to move a data file. For example, to test a backup of data files used by the offending app.

Comment: First of all, you should know that it is entirely legal for a program to keep a file open for an extended period of time. Since your question is devoid of details, nobody here can tell you why the programs you are concerned about behaves the way they do. If the file is left open *unintended*, then yes, this could be because of bugs in the software.

Comment: I edited my OP to specify (a) it's always the same app that causes the error message, and (b) the offending app is **closed** at the time that the error message is presented.